# Gulp not compiling function / following source ordering

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass, gulp-concat

I have the following in my `gulpfile.js`

```
var baseDir = 'Base/Assets/scss/**/**';
var modulesDir = 'Modules/**/Assets/scss/*'; 

return gulp.src([baseDir + '*.scss', modulesDir + '*.scss'])
    .pipe(sass({cacheLocation: sassCacheDir, lineNumbers: false}))
    .pipe(concat('app.min.css'));
```

Within the baseDir I have an app.scss file like this:

```
@import "node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/util/util";

@import "settings";
@import "foundation";
```

Within the `util` there's a function called `rem-calc`. I use this function in my `Modules` scss files, but these are never executed. Instead in the outputted css I have the following `margin-top: rem-calc(10);` when this should actually have been converted in to rem's.

The only thing I can thing of is that Gulp isn't remembering the src ordering. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: var baseDir = 'Base/Assets/scss/**/';  does that help?

Comment: No, everything which is in the baseDir compiles find and the rem-calc function is used. However, everything in the modulesDir compiles but the rem-calc function isn't used.

Comment: I do not know your directory structure but either var modulesDir = 'Modules/**/Assets/scss/**/';  or  var modulesDir = 'Modules/**/Assets/scss/';  might help.  Depends on your specific directory structure.

Comment: My structure is `Modules/MODULENAME/Assets/scss/SCSSFILE.scss` if that helps

Comment: The thing is, it is compiling these files. It's just the functions within them won't work. If I added the util import within each of these files it would work. But for some reason defining it once in the baseDir, it's not working throughout the whole compilation

Comment: So, looks like this has something to do with partials. What I want are these module files to be partials, but I don't want to specify them as @imports, these need to be dynamic as the modules can change for each project. Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by removing the modulesDir from the gulpfile, instead I'm using a new package called `gulp-sass-glob`

This allows me to specify the glob in my `app.scss` file (within baseDir), like this:

```
@import "node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/util/util";

@import "settings";
@import "foundation";

// now import the modules
@import "../../../../Modules/**/Assets/scss/*.scss";
```

My `gulpfile.js` is then like this:

```
var baseDir = 'Base/Assets/scss/**/**';

gulp.task('site-css', function () {
    return gulp.src(baseDir + '*.scss')
        .pipe(sassGlob())
        .pipe(sass({cacheLocation: sassCacheDir, lineNumbers: false}))
        .pipe(concat('app.min.css'));
```

Hopefully this helps someone else which comes across this scenario.